# Is it possible to use startWith with a wildcard in cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My if clause in a cloud function uses a wildcard with `startWith`:

```
exports.resizeImage = functions
    .storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize(async (object) => {
        if (!object.name.startsWith('venues/{uid}/bg_img')) {
            console.log(`File ${object.name} not a venue bg pic..ignoring it`);
            return null;
        }
```

I'm presuming you can't use `startsWith` with a wildcard?
If so what's the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript string [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) doesn't provide any support for wildcards.  If you want to match a file pattern, you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).  JavaScript strings provide a method called [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that you can use to test if the string matches a pattern you provide.